# Implementation of the binary division in C

Tags: c, linux, division

Here is the code which implements binary division: Here is the function where I print the final number at the end.

On Windows I get the correct answer: `60000000 7948AECA D269AE4A 6B41DD10 64209812 293E346 1C0000`
but on Linux I get only zeroes.

```
#define SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL 7

typedef struct {
  uint64_t bits[SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL];
  uint16_t scale;
  uint16_t sign;
} s21_big_decimal;

void binary_div(s21_big_decimal *value_1, s21_big_decimal value_2,
                s21_big_decimal *result) {
  init_s21_decimal(result);
  s21_big_decimal Q;
  s21_big_decimal R;
  int scaleDiv = -1;
  do {
    init_s21_decimal(&R); // fill with 0 the array
    init_s21_decimal(&Q);
    scaleDiv++;
    int lastBit = (SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1) * 32 - 1;
    int currentBit = get_bit_big(*value_1, lastBit);
    while (currentBit == 0 && lastBit >= 0) {
      currentBit = get_bit_big(*value_1, lastBit);
      if (currentBit == 0)
        lastBit--;
    }
    for (int i = lastBit; i >= 0; i--) {
      change_left_big(&R, 1);
      set_bit_big(&R, 0, get_bit_big(*value_1, i));
      if (is_less_or_equal_big(value_2, R)) {
        s21_big_decimal res = { 0 };
        init_s21_decimal(&res);
        s21_sub_big(R, value_2, &res);

        init_s21_decimal(&R);
        copy_bits(res, &R);
        set_bit_big(&Q, i, 1);
      }
    }
    if (scaleDiv > 0) {
      mul_10_big(result);
    }
    s21_big_decimal res;
    init_s21_decimal(&res);
    add_big(*result, Q, &res);
    copy_bits(res, result);
    if (!is_zero_big(R)) {
      init_s21_decimal(value_1);
      mul_10_big(&R);
      copy_bits(R, value_1);
    }
  } while (!is_zero_big(R) && scaleDiv < 28);
  set_scale_big(result, scaleDiv);
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    printf("%lX ", result->bits[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

I work with bits so here are some helper functions:

```c
int mul_10_big(s21_big_decimal *dec)
{
  s21_big_decimal temp = *dec;
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1; i++)
  {
    temp.bits[i] *= 10;
  }
  temp.scale++;
  int overflowed = 0;
  if (getoverflow(&temp))
  {
    overflowed = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    *dec = temp;
  }
  return overflowed;
}

int div_10_big(s21_big_decimal *dec)
{
  uint64_t remained = 0;
  for (int i = SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 2; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    dec->bits[i] += remained << 32;
    remained = dec->bits[i] % 10;
    dec->bits[i] /= 10;
  }
  dec->scale--;
  return remained;
}

int getoverflow(s21_big_decimal *dec)
{
  int overflow = 0;
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1; i++)
  {
    dec->bits[i] += overflow;
    overflow = (dec->bits[i] >> 32);
    dec->bits[i] &= MAX4BITE;
    count++;
  }
  int result = 0;
  if (overflow != 0 && count == 6)
  {
    result = 1;
  }
  return result;
}

void set_scale_big(s21_big_decimal *big_dec, int scale_value)
{
  big_dec->bits[SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1] &= MINUS;
  big_dec->bits[SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1] |= (scale_value << 16) & SCALE;
}
```

The problem is not in the way I print, I guess the problem is in the size of the variable. it has to work on Linux, what I have to change? Should I divide large binary numbers not this way?

Comment: For example in `div_10_big` you are returning a `uint64_t` variable, while the return type is `int`. Be consistent with types and use the fixed-width ones.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Time to start using your debugger.

Comment: Please provide a demonstration of your problem. What you posted isn't complete.

Comment: Also, the difference is not only in the operating system. There is probably also difference in the compiler. Disclose which compilers you use in each case and what compilation options you use in each case.

Comment: This looks wrong: `lastBit = (SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1) * 32 - 1;`.  Your big digits are 64 bits wide, but you appear to be calculating the index of the last bit as if they were only 32 bits wide.

Comment: ... in fact, the `SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1` looks wrong, too.  The total number of bits in a `uint64_t[SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL]` is `SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL * 64`, and if you number them starting from 0 then the last number used is `SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL * 64 - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- The return type of `div_10_big` should be `uint64_t` instead of `int` but this does not pose a problem because the return value, the remainder of the division in in the range 0..9.
- It is unclear why you do not iterate on all elements in the loops in functions `div_10_big`, `getoverflow`, and `mul_10_big`.
- It is unclear why `set_scale_big` modifies the array instead of just the `scale` member.
- The type `s21_big_decimal` can handle values much larger than the traditional one for `s21_decimal`, i.e. `-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335` to `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335`, with a scale from `0` to `28`, but using `uint64_t` for the `bits` seems overkill as you only use 32 bits for each of these `bits`.  Tracking overflow in the individual operation handlers would allow for a more compact representation.
- The `printf` in the output code actually has undefined behavior on Windows: in `printf("%lX ", result->bits[i])`, you pass an `unsigned long long` where `printf` expects an `unsigned long`. For a portable version you should use:

  ```
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL; i++) {
        printf("%08llX ", (unsigned long long)result->bits[i]);
    }
  ```

Comment: Since `result->bits[i]` is really an `uint64_t`, better include `<inttypes.h>` and print with `printf("%" PRIX64 " ", result->bits[i]);`.